# focus state return to normal on mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, ipad, focus, css-transitions

I am using .css to create a portfolio webpage for my art. I am using a floating box layout to display each piece of art separately with a .focus tag so when an image is clicked it expands, clicked again to return it to normal. The problem I am having is that the site **works fine on desktops, but not on mobile devices** (ipads). In the case of ipads (using safari), the **.focus will work to expand an image, but I cannot return the image to its original state.** With Safari on my desktop, the image will return to its normal state, but I have to click away from it to do so.

I would like to keep this site .css/html only if possible.

**This is .css code from the relevant style sheet**

```
  vert1{
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    }
  vert1 img{
    width:auto%; 
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 0s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 0s ease;  
    transition: all 0s ease;  
    }
  vert1:focus{
    }
  vert1:focus img{
    width: auto;
    height: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 25;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 0s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 0s ease;  
    transition: all 0s ease;  
    }
```

**and this is its implementation in html**

```
  <div class="img">
    <vert1 tabindex="1"><img src="7woman.jpg"></vert1><br />
    title/medium/size
  </div>
```

**here is a link to the site**
[www.kurtkindermann.com](http://www.kurtkindermann.com)

**and a link to the above code in action**
[www.kurtkindermann.com/mix.html](http://www.kurtkindermann.com/mix.html)

Thank you!